# Update on "user" and "technicien" with one to one connection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have two tables user and technician with one to one connection, technician inherits from user. After editing technician information through edit form and saving no update happens on tables user and technician. and no errors as well.

Here is my code:

Controllers

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = $technicien->user;
    return view('technicien.edit',['technicien'=>$technicien])->with('user',$user);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation

    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    $technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
    $user->nom = $request->update('nom');

    return redirect('/technicien');
    }
```

View

```
 @extends('Layouts/app')
 @extends('Layouts.master')
 @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $technicien->technicien  ) }}" method="update">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


             <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nom">Nom</label>
            <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[nom]" value="{{$user->nom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[prenom]" value="{{$user->prenom}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prenom">Email</label>
            <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-  control" name="user[email]" value="{{$user->email}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
            <input type="text"  name="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->moyenne_avis}}" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
            <input type="text"  name="actif" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->actif}}" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="enregistrer"        class="form-control btn btn-primary">
        </div>
            </div>




        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/technicien/{id}/edit', 'TechnicienController@edit');
Route::patch('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update')->name('technicien.update');
```

Model1

```
<?php

namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class technicien extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = [
    'moyenne_avis', 'actif',
];
use SoftDeletes;
protected $guarded = [];
 protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    public function zoneintervention()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\zoneintervention','technicien_zone','technicien_id','zoneintervention_id');

}
    public function metier()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\metier','technicien_metier','technicien_id','metier_id');

}
 public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

 public function tarificationtache()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\tarificationtache','technicien_tarificationtache','technicien_id','tarificationtache_id');
  }


}
```

Model2

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
public function technicien()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\technicien');

}

use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'email', 'password','nom','prenom','tel','mobil','role',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controler

```
public function edit($id)
{
// better to use findOrFail (it will throw an exception about missing 
objects)
$technicien = technicien::findOrFail($id);
return view('technicien.edit', compact('technicien'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
$technicien=technicien::findOrFail($id);
$technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
$technicien->update($request->get('technicien'));
return redirect('/technicien');
}
```

and the view

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
  <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
            <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $technicien ) }}"         
                method="post">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                {{ method_field('patch') }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nom">Nom</label>
                    <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[nom]" value="{{$technicien->user->nom}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[prenom]" value="{{$technicien->user->prenom}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[tel]" value="{{$technicien->user->tel}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[mobil]" value="{{$technicien->user->mobil}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[role]" value="{{$technicien->user->role}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Email</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[email]" value="{{$technicien->user->email}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="prenom">Email</label>
                    <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" 
name="user[password]" value="{{$technicien->user->password}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="technicien[moyenne_avis]" 
class="form-control" value="{{$technicien->moyenne_avis}}" >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
                    <input type="text"  name="technicien[actif]" 
 class="form-control" value="{{$technicien->actif}}" >
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="enregistrer" class="form-
 control btn btn-primary">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do with One to One relation. 
Make relation for user table and technician table, then try to do update.

Comment: can u show me the model, also ur table name is technicien or technicienes

Comment: I added my two models and mytable's name is technicien

Answer (score 0):

Try this in controller

```
$user = User::with('technicien')->find($id);
$data['id'] = $id;

$data = $this->validate($request, [
        'moyenne_avis' => 'required',
]);

$user->technicien()->whereUserId($data['id'])->update(['moyenne_avis' => $data['moyenne_avis']
]);

return redirect('/technicien')->with('Success', 'Records updated');
```

Also change form method as below in ur view.blade

```
<form action="{{ action('TechnicienController@update', $user->id) }}" method="post">
```

also, instead of `{{ method_field('PATCH') }}` use this `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">`

> **Note: Table name should be plural for controller and model name.
>
>       eg: Table name:      users
>           Controller name: UserController
>           Model name:      User**
>   Make sure this same in urs too.

Comment: Route::patch('/technicien/{id}', 'TechnicienController@update');

Comment: ur table name cannot be technicien, it should be technicienes

Comment: conform method is changed and hidden field is added in view.blade.php

Comment: Could you explain me more please ?

Comment: When i changed to POST it created a new technicien and kept the old one

Comment: ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property of non-object